# InsertionSort in descending order

Tags: c++, algorithm, insertion-sort

I have been trying to do InsertionSort in descending order but have been failing miserably.

Below is the code I have written

```
void InsertionSortInDecrementing(int arr[], const size_t size) {
  for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    int currentElement = arr[i];
    size_t previousElementIndex = i - 1;
    while (previousElementIndex > 0 && currentElement > arr[previousElementIndex]) {
      arr[previousElementIndex + 1] = arr[previousElementIndex];
      --previousElementIndex;
    }
    arr[previousElementIndex + 1] = currentElement;
  }
}
```

For a sample array, the biggest element does move to the left but the biggest element gets stuck at position 1 and does not move to position 0 and if I change the condition in the while statement to `>=` it results in a segmentation fault in C++.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: The inner `while` loop terminates when `previousElementIndex == 0`, and afterwards the element is placed in `arr[previousElementIndex + 1]`, i.e., nowhere can it be placed in `arr[0]` since the minimum is `arr[0 + 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have an array like `{1, 2}`. `previousElementIndex` will start at `0` but your inner loop will not execute because the first condition `previousElementIndex > 0` is false in this case. This is why your element gets stuck at position one. To fix this you have to change `>` to `>=`, but then you will also have to change `previousElementIndex`'s type to `int` to handle when it becomes -1.

Comment: That fixed the issue. That makes complete sense, now that previousElementIndex is size_t it will not have an overflow and a signed int would make the value -1.
Thanks!